# Why is the Formidable `form.parse` callback not running in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

I am using the [`formidable`](https://npm.im/formidable) package to handle file uploads on my server.
This is my `express.js` app code:

```javascript
var formidable = require("formidable"),
  http = require("http"),
  util = require("util");
app.post("/admin/uploads", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.files, req.fields); //It prints
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    console.log("Inside form parse."); //its not printing
    console.log(err, fields, files); //its not printing
  });
  form.on("file", function (name, file) {
    console.log("file=" + file);
  }); //its not printing
  form.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }); //its not printing
  form.on("aborted", function () {
    console.log("Aborted");
  }); //its not printing
  console.log(form); //it prints
});
```

In the above code, the `form.parse` and `form.on` callbacks are never run. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem when using Next.js API routes with Formidable. Like the other answer points out, you have to remove the body parser. In Next.js, you can export a `config` object and disable body parsing.

```js
// /pages/api/form.js
import { IncomingForm } from "formidable";

export default function handler(req, res) {
  // formidable logic
}

// VV important VV
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: This answer was actually helpful for me. One thing, as a Next.js newbie I tried to export the config from my current file. You actually need to export it **from the api handler** to work

Answer (score 13):

It might be that you need to remove body parser

```
delete app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: That was exactly the reason in my case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please add the error handlers and send the error message otherwise it is hard to get an answer.

```
form.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); });
form.on('aborted', function() { console.log('Aborted'); });
```

See the `formidable` documentation : [doc](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)

Comment: Nothing is printing inside form methods.

Answer (score 1):

Call `form.parse(...)` after all `on(...)` events.

```
app.post('/admin/uploads', function(req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(); 
    form.on('file', function(name, file) { });
    form.on('error', function(err) { });
    form.on('aborted', function() { });
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) { });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to my html form, maybe this will help somebody :)

Comment: That is a pretty general pitfall: please argue why this might well have been the problem here, given the absence of client side code.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you remove `body-parser` and use `express.json()` etc... you will have same error.

The problem is that `express.raw()` is causing trouble remove it and it works!